# Why is qobject_cast required in this SLOT for sender()?

Tags: c++, qt

From calculator example of Qt:

```
void Calculator::digitClicked()
{
    Button *clickedButton = qobject_cast<Button *>(sender());
    int digitValue = clickedButton->text().toInt();
    if (display->text() == "0" && digitValue == 0.0)
        return;

    if (waitingForOperand) {
        display->clear();
        waitingForOperand = false;
    }
    display->setText(display->text() + QString::number(digitValue));
}
```

This SLOT is connected to all digit buttons:

```
digitButtons[i] = createButton (QString::number(i), SLOT(digitClicked()));
```

With `createButton`:

```
Button *Calculator::createButton(const QString &text, const char *member)
{
    Button *button = new Button(text);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, member);
    return button;
}
```

**So, in the SLOT why is type cast required?**

```
Button *clickedButton = qobject_cast<Button *>(sender());
```

Comment: did you try to remove the cast to see what the compiler will tell you?

Comment: Because it needs to access `Button` members in `digitClicked` slot, and `sender()` returns a `QObject` type. In Qt 5 you could use lambdas to call the slot with the button's text passed as a parameter.

Comment: @thuga Thankful to you too. I should have checked the return type of sender.

Comment: Note that using sender() is considered unclean. Use lambdas or QSignalMapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `sender()` returns a `QObject*`, so you will not be able to call methods of the underlying object until it is downcasted.

`qobject_cast` performs the downcast, while checking at runtime the underlying object is effectively of the required type. This is similar to standard `dynamic_cast`, except it has a reduced cost due to Qt's meta-object facilities (but it only works with classes derived from `QObject`).

See Qt's documentation about [meta-object system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html).